# How to rewrite this implicit where join into explicit join

Tags: sql, join

```
 SELECT * FROM `users` u, `markers` m,`imagemarkers` im
 WHERE u.username LIKE '%test%'
  OR u.email LIKE '%test%'
  OR u.location LIKE '%test%'
  OR m.author LIKE '%test%'
  OR m.bike LIKE '%test%'
  OR m.title LIKE '%test%'
```

I came across this SQL in a question, but was unable to provide an answer, because I refuse to write `where join` queries.

Does this implicit join give the expected (short) result, or does this give a cross join and why?
How do I rewrite this using explicit joins, without adding new conditions, so no match on (user.id = markers.user_id) and such.

Answer (score 3):

This is a cross join. Try something like this (Please note that I suppose markers table and imagemarkers table has a reference to the users table. This may well not be the case!)

```
SELECT * FROM `users` u, `markers` m,`imagemarkers` im
 WHERE m.user_id = i.id AND im.user_id = u.id
  AND (u.username LIKE '%test%'
  OR u.email LIKE '%test%'
  OR u.location LIKE '%test%'
  OR m.author LIKE '%test%'
  OR m.bike LIKE '%test%'
  OR m.title LIKE '%test%')
```

I'm not sure what you mean by 'explicit join' but my guess is:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` u 
 inner join `markers` m on (m.user_id = i.id) 
 inner join  `imagemarkers` im on (im.user_id = u.id) 
 WHERE u.username LIKE '%test%'
  OR u.email LIKE '%test%'
  OR u.location LIKE '%test%'
  OR m.author LIKE '%test%'
  OR m.bike LIKE '%test%'
  OR m.title LIKE '%test%'
```

Comment: I meant rewrite without altering the behaviour of the query.

Comment: @Johan, sorry but the original select you posted in the question simply does not make any sense, or to be more precise this is what it exactly does: 1) filter users table, keep records where username or email is like "test" 2) do some similar filtering on markers table 3) take the filtered users table, the filtered markers table and the unfiltered imagemarkers table and create a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of these three. I was sure you wanted to alter this behaviour.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted to find out. I wanted to know 1: how to express the exact same result using explicit join syntax 2: is this a cross join or not. You've answered point 2.

Comment: OK, `SELECT * FROM users u CROSS JOIN markers m CROSS JOIN imagemarkers im`. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join